# Python Searching for specic error message in specific files , but the loop output twice

Tags: python, search, text

```
import os
import sys
import re
import fnmatch
from time import sleep
#The colours of the things
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
pattern = ['*.results','*.reports','*.log','*.sum','*.summary','*.spi','*.log','*.ext','*.sum','*.summary','*.spi','*.info']
search_str = "ERROR:"
mystring = search_str.encode('utf-8')
#print len(sys.argv)
print ('checking for errors in', sys.argv[1])
if len(sys.argv) < 1:
    sys.exit('Usage: check_error.py <build directory>')
for x in pattern:
  for path,dirs,files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for fname in files:
        # Test the filename for particular pattern matches.
      if fnmatch.fnmatch(fname,x):
        fullpath = os.path.join(path,fname)
        with open(fullpath,'rb') as f:
           line = f.read()
           # Initialize counter for line number
           line_no = 1
           # Loop until EOF
           if line != '' :
           # Search for string in line
             index = line.find(mystring.lower())
             if ( index != -1) :
                 print(bcolors.FAIL + '[-]' + bcolors.ENDC + ' ', fname, ' ', search_str , ' ' , 'exists! Please check', ' ', fullpath, sep="" ) 
                 print('      ')
                 sleep(0.01)
             else:
                 print(bcolors.OKGREEN + '[+]' + bcolors.ENDC + ' ',  fname, ' ', 'OK!', sep="")
                 print("       ")
                 sleep(0.01)
                # Increment line counter
                 line_no += 1
```

output looks like

```
[+] prefix.log OK!
      
[-] test.log ERROR: exists! Please check logs/test.log
      
[-] test.sum ERROR: exists! Please check logs/test.sum

[+] prefix.log OK!
       
[-] test.log ERROR: exists! Please check logs/test.log
      
[-] test.sum ERROR: exists! Please check logs/test.sum
```

Please give a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing output for the `*.log` and `*.sum` files twice because these patterns appear twice in your pattern list. Remove the duplicates and you will see the output that you expect (I think).

```
pattern = ['*.results','*.reports','*.log','*.sum', ... '*.log','*.ext','*.sum', ...]
```

Comment: I hope this resolved your problem. Please "accept" my answer (click on the check mark) to mark your question as resolved.